# what are the most used interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, interface

I tried searching for the most used built-in interfaces in C#, but couldn't find an article, so I thought we may recap here.

Let's use the following convention in the answers:

IinterfaceName1: for this

IinterfaceName2: for that

Comment: Fifty points to whomever first writes a script to e.g. scour all the C# code on github and provide statistics about the most-used-interfaces.  :)

Comment: Completely unscientific, but http://www.google.com/insights/search/#q=ienumerable%2Cinotifypropertychanged%2Cidisposable%2Cilist&cmpt=q

Comment: +1 for asking a VERY IMPORTANT QUESTION. See my answer for the CORRECT answer, I can't down vote the answer bellow as I have a bounty running:(

Comment: On your machine: ICorDebug probably.  I'm guessing that's not what you asked for :)

Comment: DOWNVOTE @dahlbyk response its IT'S WRONG!!!!!!! see my response for correct answer!!! This is veeeery important!

Comment: @ivo: You are wrong; he is right.

Comment: @ivo It's not really that important.

Comment: Why close? There are clearly some interfaces that are used more than others, and highlighting the commonly-used ones can be helpful for those new to the framework...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The top two in my mind have to be ones with language support:

- `IEnumerable<T>` (and `IEnumerable`): for
  use with `foreach` and LINQ
- `IDisposable`: for resources requiring
  cleanup, used with `using`

Beyond that...

- `IComparable<T>` and `IComparer<T>`: for generalized sorting
- `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`: for generalized equality
- `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>`: for mutable collections
- `IDictionary<T,K>`: for lookup collections

Comment: Agree with all the above, would only add IBindingList & INotifyPropertyChanged for data binding in WinForms

Comment: Not as common as the collection interfaces, but `ISerializable` is important as well.

Comment: @CodeInChaos meh; only really `BinaryFormatter` uses that, and `BinaryFormatter` has a *whole range* of things making it undesirable. Thinks like `XmlSerializer`, json, etc don't make any use of `ISerializable`, and I'd argue that more recent code uses xml/json etc than it does remoting

Answer (score 11):

`INotifyPropertyChange` : For data binding to UI classes in WPF, winforms and silverlight

Comment: Winforms (and, IIRC WPF) also support the *Changed pattern

Answer (score 5):

`IQueryable<T>`: lets you execute requests against queriable data sources. For example

```
        IQueryable<Project> projects = db.Projects;
        var selectedItems = projects
            .Where(x => x.Workers.Count() > 10 && x.Status != 1)
            .ToArray();
```

In this example filtering would be done on SQL Server (in involves tricky mechanics with translating Expression `x => x.Workers.Count() > 10 && x.Status != 1` to SQL statements)
So no need to write custom SQL commands to use all might of data source.

Also can be used not only with SQL, you can query objects or anything else, just find implementation of `IQueryable<T>`