# Most Popular/Frequently Used/Important Interfaces in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

Apart from IEnumerable, IComparable, what other "important" (or frequently used) interfaces are there for me to know in C#.NET?

Comment: Do they have to be interfaces?

Comment: IComparer, IEquatable, IDisposable (love this one)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are the most used interfaces in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c/4240764#4240764)

Copy-Paste from there:

- `IEnumerable<T>` (and `IEnumerable`): for use with foreach and LINQ
- `IDisposable`: for resources requiring cleanup, used with using
- `IQueryable<T>`: lets you execute requests against queriable data sources.
- `INotifyPropertyChange`: For data binding to UI classes in WPF, winforms and silverlight
- `IComparable<T>` and `IComparer<T>`: for generalized sorting
- `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`: for generalized equality
- `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>`: for mutable collections
- `IDictionary<T,K>`: for lookup collections

Answer (score 15):

**[`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)** is pretty important.

Answer (score 9):

There's LOTS

- IDisposable
- `IComparer<T>`
- `IComparable<T>`
- ISerializable
- `IEquatable<T>`
- `ICollection<T>`
- INotifyPropertyChanged
- IEditableObject (used in RIA services a fair bit)

This are only the ones that come to mind right now.

Comment: I wouldn't say `IEquatable<T>` is more important than `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 5):

Also:

- ICloneable and
- IFormatter / IFormatProvider

Comment: Note that the [MS framework guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/05/03/125427.aspx) state: `Do not implement ICloneable` because of Shallow/DeepClone ambiguity (which is probably also the reason a generic ICloneable was never created)

Answer (score 4):

[ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28VS.80%29.aspx) is used frequently

Answer (score 3):

if your doing WPF/Silverlight then INotifyPropertyChanged is your best friend.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe no one has mentioned IQueryable or IQueryProvider