# Common type of implement interfaces

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, interface

I am not clear on how to post this question, but to express in a way, I would say could you please list what all are the common type of interface implementations are to be used, I commonly only use INotifyPropertyChanged, but recently only I came to know the requirements of using the IValueConverter, and much more newly, today, I came to know to use IDisposable,  hence, could you please list the most commonly used implements.
I know this question is not properly put forward because the implements are based on program logic requirements, but i want to know so that I can be informed of what they are and what I need to do for a situation.
Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are the most used interfaces in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240438/what-are-the-most-used-interfaces-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll be hard-pressed to get a concise answer here, because "it depends" on what you are doing and what type of applications you are developing.  The best way to learn, IMHO, is by example and finding and surrounding yourself with the right resources (people and paper) to guide you.

I won't directly answer your question either :), but take a broader look at frameworks and open source projects built in .NET, see how they are put together.  Do some investigation of design patterns and what concepts and paradigms are used in the types of scenarios you are building apps for - I particularly like the following:

> [doFactory: Design Patterns in .NET](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)
>
> [.NET Framework Guidelines and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184412.aspx)
>
> [Framework Design Guidelines](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/framework-design-guidelines-krzysztof-cwalina/1100835446)
>
> [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)

but there are a host of other great references and software craftsman out there in the blogosphere.

In general, my philosophy is to adopt and be conversant with tried-and-true software patterns and then the specifics of 'details' like the interfaces will naturally appear. Try it vice-versa, and it's kind of like attempting to memorize a dictionary.

Comment: Thansk, this is what I am looking for, I am a developer since 7 years and still low on information.  The second link you provided is the same as first one.

Comment: thanks, I fixed the link, and glad the information is helpful!